# OpenMp - Processing Single Array

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a multi-threaded application(OpenMP), in which each thread do some calculations and find the value of _pre. 
    Then a file with name "file_pre.txt" is opened and write the part of the string starting from index _sub and _end.
    It should not happen that two threads having the same file name open the file for writing.
    Hence the writing part I wrote in critical section but it's expensive because I would like multiple threads having different file name to be able to write in the respective files simultaneously, and only lock them out when they have same value in _pre (same file name) (the updating thread could wait for the other threads to finish).

Does anyone have a solution?

PART OF CODE:

```
ofstream outfile;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) schedule(static) private(it) shared(array)
for (it = 0; it < array.size(); ++it) 
{
            int _pre, _sub = 0, _end;
             if(---)
            {        
                    _pre = xyz;
                                    _end = abc;
                                    ostringstream strCounter;
                                    strCounter << _pre;
                                    string result = "file" + strCounter.str() + ".txt";
                    #pragma omp critical(outfile)
                                        {
                                        outfile.open(result.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
                                        if (outfile.is_open()) 
                                            {
                                            for (int count = _sub; count < _end; count++) 
                                            {
                                                outfile << buffer[count];
                                            }
                                            outfile << "\n";
                                            outfile.close();
                                           } else cout << "Unable to open file";
                                        _sub = _abc;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    _pre = _xyz_;
                                    _end = _abc_;
                                    ostringstream strCounter;
                                    strCounter << _pre;
                                    string result = "file" + strCounter.str() + ".txt";
                    #pragma omp critical(outfile)
                                        {
                                        outfile.open(result.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
                                        if (outfile.is_open()) 
                                            {
                                            for (int count = _sub; count < _end; count++) 
                                            {
                                                outfile << buffer[count];
                                            }
                                            outfile << "\n";
                                            outfile.close();
                                           } else cout << "Unable to open file";
                                        _sub = _abc;
                    }

            }

}
```

Comment: Is that concievable that you keep a map with the filenames in memory? If so, associating it with locks could be a solution. You'd only have to keep the access and/or modification of the map inside `critical` sections

Comment: @Gilles - Thank you for the suggestion. I am new to OpenMP, I may be asking a very basic question, but as I haven't been able to find its solutions.
Where should I take a lock on?
1) file pointer 'myfile'(ofstream myfile)
2) the name of file where conflict will happen if two threads try to open the file with the same name? 
[OR]
Should I declare an array of lock (one lock for each file name ( i.e. from 1 to 256), as if threads calculated the file name to be different they can write respective files simultaneously.

Comment: Does any previous iteration in the main `for` loop have any impact on successive iterations?

Comment: @WilliamMiller No they (main for loop iterations)  are completely independent.

Comment: @Tjcool It may be appropriate to use `std::thread`s instead of OpenMP as this would allow finer-grain control. If you are compiling with C++11 or newer that is. You can do that even if other sections of the program are in OpenMP. If you are interested in how to do that I can compose an answer elaborating.

Comment: @WilliamMiller - We are using –std=c++11
I would really appreciate if you Elaborate answer. Thank you